# I want to write some mathematical sentences in the English language

Tags: grammar, mathematics

I want to write these mathematical sentences in the pure English language:

```
In this paper, for every vertex a v in G, we find a shortest path joining v and w in G.
```

My proposed sentences are:

```
In this paper, we (will(?)) find a shortest path joining w, and any arbitrary vertex in the graph.
```

Is it true?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Writing advice? Maybe OT.

Comment: What is the OT?!!

Comment: Welcome to ELU. OT: Off-Topic, some kinds of question are considered off topic on this site. Please see FAQ. http://english.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

"In this paper, we define an algorithm for finding the shortest path between any two vertices of a finite, connected graph."

Comment: @user112887 Ohhh. Sorry, I assumed you were doing a proof for a general graph. If you've got a fixed G with a fixed w in G. I'd go with "In this paper, we identify the shortest path between w and all other vertices in G."